# How to pass parameter to View Component via Asp .Net Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to pass some value to the View Component from the controller. I tried differently but it does not transmit. If I don't pass anything to the constructor then everything works fine, but when I try to pass it to the constructor it doesn't even call the ViewComponent

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddToCart(int id)
{
    return ViewComponent("Cart", new {id});
}
```

View Component:

```
public class CartViewComponent : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent
{
    int gId;

    public CartViewComponent(int id)
    {
        gId = id;
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to create a class that has an int property: `id` and take that as a parameter in the component instead of just an int.

Comment: Do you mean to create a class by type as a model in which there will be an Id property?
And pass it to the View Component?

Comment: Yes, that is what you are passing right now, but the vc is expecting just an int. But have tried just passing `id` instead of `new {id}` ?

Comment: Forget what I said, look at the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Invoking a view component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0#invoking-a-view-component) includes the following explanation:

> The parameters will be passed to the `InvokeAsync` method.

This means you should move your `id` parameter from the constructor to the `Invoke` method:

```
public class CartViewComponent : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int id)
    {
        // Use id here.
        return View();
    }
}
```